What is the real value of $\cos 1^\circ$?
There are nice formulas for the trigonometric functions of $15^\circ$ and $18^\circ$
$$\begin{aligned}
&\cos 15^\circ = \frac{\sqrt6+\sqrt2}4&&\qquad\sin 15^\circ = \frac{\sqrt6-\sqrt2}4\\
&\cos 18^\circ = \frac{5+\sqrt5}{2\sqrt2}&&\qquad\sin 18^\circ = \frac{\sqrt5-1}4\\
\end{aligned}$$
Together with the angle difference identities
$$\begin{cases}
\cos(A-B) &= \sin A\sin B+\cos A\cos B\\
\sin(A-B) &= \sin A\cos B-\cos A\sin B
\end{cases}$$
this gives us
$$\begin{aligned}
\cos 3^\circ = \cos(18-15)^\circ
&= \left(\frac{5+\sqrt5}{2\sqrt2}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt6+\sqrt2}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{\sqrt5-1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt6-\sqrt2}{4}\right)\\\\
&= \frac{2(5+\sqrt5)(\sqrt3+1)+(\sqrt5-1)(\sqrt6-\sqrt2)}{16}
\end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned}
\sin 3^\circ = \sin(18-15)^\circ
&= \left(\frac{5+\sqrt5}{2\sqrt2}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt6-\sqrt2}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{\sqrt5-1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt6+\sqrt2}{4}\right)\\\\
&= \frac{2(5+\sqrt5)(\sqrt3-1)+(\sqrt5-1)(\sqrt6+\sqrt2)}{16}
\end{aligned}$$
Now what abou $\cos 1^\circ$? There is a triple angle formula $\cos 3A = -3\cos A+4\cos^3 A$ which says $\cos 1^\circ$ a root of the equation
$$a = -3x+4x^3$$
where $a := \cos 3^\circ$. Cardano's formula finally gives us
$$\cos 1^\circ = \frac12\left(\sqrt[3]{a+i\sqrt{1-a^2}}+\sqrt[3]{a-i\sqrt{1-a^2}}\right)$$
but this is no good. There are complex numbers in this formula, and $\cos 1^\circ$ is not a complex number. How do I get rid of them so that $\cos 1^\circ$ is written in terms of real numbers only? Is this even possible? It doesn't seem right I should require complex numbers to represent quantities that are definitely real.
This probably does not help with the task at hand, but one could notice $\sqrt{1-a^2}$ is just $\sin 3^\circ$ so our formula can be rewritten as
$$\cos 1^\circ = \frac12\left(\sqrt[3]{\cos 3^\circ+i\sin 3^\circ}+\sqrt[3]{\cos 3^\circ-i\sin 3^\circ}\right).$$
I am aware complex numbers were widespread with the very purpose of solving cubic equations. This means its impossible to avoid them?

The term-of-art for this issue is "casus irreducibilis". The Wikipedia article gives a discussion; a web search (and/or Math.SE site search) can provide different takes on the situation.

As you see, the cubic formula is one approach. An lararming fact is the cubic formula really does require complex numbers. (Well, some instances of the cubic formula were solved independently, but the single-form answer, which greatly simplifies the answer, requires complex numbers.)

@Alma Arjuna, Patiently continuing with long surds further.. choose the real root of the cubic after discarding two complex roots. Long result but not so nice.

Yes, strangely enough (by some standard), it is impossible to avoid complex numbers when expressing general cosines (or sines) of $n$th parts of a circle. Yes, they are expressible in radicals (!), but those radical expression mostly take us outside the real numbers.
Yes, as you say, solving cubic equations in radicals, even when the solutions are real numbers, typically requires complex numbers. This became clear in an ad-hoc way centuries ago. It became clearer to me, personally, some years ago when I saw how Lagrange resolvents give a way to solve-in-radicals equations with cyclic Galois groups.

But why!? What is stopping us? I mean, is there a theorem stating this is impossible? How could something like this be even proven?

How could something like this be even proven? --- See my 26 September 2005 sci.math post for historical and expository references. By the way, about 20 years ago I made a translation of Mostowski's paper that I mention in that sci.math post.
